# How to disable ViewCell but keep enabled Grid inside it?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, grid, gesture-recognition

I have structure in xaml filie like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How to disable clicking on ListView because of default orange background color of selected item, but keep enabled Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your Android project

> in Resource-->values-->style.xml

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@null</item>

<item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@null</item>

<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the `ListView.SelectionMode` property:
`SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;`

Official doc can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.selectionmode?view=xamarin-forms).

Comment: Well it's pritty much it... :D
But still there is some "blinking" effect on background. It's grey transparent. Not big deal, but is there any solution to disable even that?

Comment: On which platform the blinking appears?

Comment: On Android platform.